# .scroll() to top does not work with .location.reload();

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the jQuery `.location.reload();` to refresh the page and then `.scroll()` to scroll to the top of the page. Both functions work when implemented alone.

However, when I try to implement both together, the page does not scroll to the top. It initially appears to scroll to the top but is then dragged back to the bottom of the page.

```
function cancelUpdate(){
    $(".cancel-update" ).click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         location.reload();
         $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast'); 
         setTimeout(function () {
             // $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');   
         }, 5500);
     });
  }
```

I tried setting the scroll to top within a `setTimeout` function- just  in case jQuery needed time to execute the function, but it was to no avail.

Comment: first animate it to top and then reload page

Comment: when you reload the page all you javascript is rerun once again. so that code after  location.reload(); won't  be executed anyway. What you could do is to add some state via bowser.history or url hash so that after page is reloaded another part of your code could take it over and do scrolling

Comment: i dont know how to do what u suggest Shershen. can you show me some sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways, the first one is to scroll your page first before reloading. The second one you could try to check whether the scroll is on top of the page or not after reloading, if not then scroll to top.

Second way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('html').scrollTop() != 0)
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
});
```

Comment: hello user26409021. i tried what you suggested but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

As soon as location.reload() is executed all the following code is lost considering that the page is refreshed.
Try making to functions...one for the click event that will execute the reload...and another one that will be executed on page load to make the scroll.

Comment: hello Ovidiu. i tried what you suggest but it does not work

Comment: The function that make the scroll should be placed inside a $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready()....the default browser behavior will scroll the page to the position it was before the reload after $(document).ready().

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with two separate functions. The first one scrolls to the desired position and is executed after the page load; the second one changes the location to the same page with different parameters (use of cookies is also considerable).

When the user perform a certain action you call the redirect with `reloadPage(0)`.

```
function reloadPage(pos){
    window.location = 'http://www.yourpage.com?position=' + pos;
}
```

After the page loads you can trigger `autoScroll()`

```
function autoScroll(){
    var parameters = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var position, splitParam;
    for(var i=0; i<parameters.length; i++){
        splitParam = parameters[i].split("=");
        if(splitParam[0] == "position"){
            position = splitParam[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(position){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: position}, 'fast');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I had to wrap everything inside the timeout function

```
$('.cancel-update').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function() 
  {
    location.reload();  //Scroll to top and Refresh page
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
  }, 5500);
});
```